# C translation phase 4

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Recently I encountered the following issue. My implementation was looking like this:

```
#define MY_CODE_VERSION PROJ_VERSION
#include "project.h"
if (3 != MY_CODE_VERSION)
```

PROJ_VERSION was defined in project.h. Why didn't I get a compilaton warning/error? Because I was trying to define something on a macro that was not known by the time the compiler was reaching the line `#define MY_CODE_VERSION PROJ_VERSION`.
I took a look over these phases from ANSI C but I can't figure it out the reason (the actual behaviour of the compiler, at which phase MY_CODE_VERSION takes the value of PROJ_VERSION).

My assuption is that this replacement takes place only at line "#if (3 != MY_CODE_VERSION)" and by this time PROJ_VERSION is already known by the compiler from the inclusion of project.h above.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please format code correctly in your question. Code lines should have four spaces at least in front of them. Use the `edit` link (and also motivate your question). Provide some [MCVE]. BTW, the current C standard is C11 (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). ANSI C is obsolete

Comment: Your assumption seems plausible (I am using it, too.) Your question is about a quote from standard to put it on a firm foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll not hash out what you already know. What you apparently did *not* know:

> **6.10.3.4** **Rescanning and further replacement**
>
> 1. After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing
>      tokens are removed. Then, the resulting preprocessing token sequence
>      is rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the
>      source file, for more macro names to replace.
> 2. If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
>      preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested
>      replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not
>      replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no
>      longer available for further replacement even if they are later
>      (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token
>      would otherwise have been replaced.
> 3. The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it
>      resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are
>      then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.

In short, once a macro has been expanded and all the string-izer and concatenations have been performed, the resulting "thing" is scanned once again for more stuff to replace. If the same name is found, it is *not* replaced.

So what you're seeing is standard-defined.